# Running multiple scrapy spiders inside Klein/Twisted

Tags: python, asynchronous, scrapy, twisted

currently I'm working on a spider-project running as an API, hence I did some research on running scrapy inside an HTTP-server. For simpleness I went for Python Klein, basically following this:

https://github.com/betinacosta/scrapy-klein-tutorial/blob/master/README%5BEN-US%5D.md

Currently, my code looks like this (Python 3.9):

```
import json
import os

from klein import Klein
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from twisted.web.server import Site

Site.displayTracebacks = False


class TwistedRunner(CrawlerRunner):

    def crawl(self, Spider, *args, **kwargs):
        self.items = []

        # create spider instance
        crawler = self.create_crawler(Spider)
        crawler.signals.connect(self.storeItem, signals.item_scraped)

        # create deferred crawler-object and register callback
        deferred = self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        deferred.addCallback(self.getItems)

        return deferred

    def storeItem(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def getItems(self, item):
        return self.items

def getSpiderResult(output):
    """Format spider result"""

    return json.dumps([dict(item) for item in output])


class Router(object):
    app = Klein()
    scrapeArgument = os.getenv('argument', 'product').encode()

    @app.route('/<path:catchall>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def catchAll(self, request, catchall):
        """catch-all route"""

        request.redirect('/')

    @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def scrape(self, request):
        """Serve request for scrape"""

        if self.scrapeArgument not in request.args:
            return None

        Runner = TwistedRunner()
        product=request.args.get(self.scrapeArgument).pop()
        a = Runner.crawl(MySpiderCls, product=product)
        a.addCallback(getSpiderResult)
        return a


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Router = Router()
    Router.app.run(os.getenv('address', '0.0.0.0'), os.getenv('port', 8080))
```

This works fine, just as expected. Now, I'd love to run multiple spiders from this point. The documentation is very clear about that:

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html

However, when I do something like

```
runner = CrawlerRunner()
runner.crawl(MySpider1)
runner.crawl(MySpider2)
d = runner.join()
```

I see all spiders running, however as soon as the first spider finishes, the HTTP request is finished. At this point, there might be spiders not being finished yet, hence I'm missing items. To illustrate this behavior see some example log:

```
2021-07-29 21:14:27+0200 [-] save item
2021-07-29 21:14:27+0200 [-] (TCP Port 6024 Closed)
2021-07-29 21:14:27+0200 [-] "127.0.0.1" - - [29/Jul/2021:19:14:27 +0000] "GET /?product=anything HTTP/1.1" 200 3 "-" "curl/7.78.0"
2021-07-29 21:14:27+0200 [-] save item
```

As you can see, the finally saved item will never be echoed back to the user since the requests is finished right above.

Does anybody know how to run multiple spiders from this setup? Also, in case there is anything I'm not doing according to the scrapy-doctrine, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're using a subclass of `CrawlerRunner` and you've overloaded the `crawl()` method such that it doesn't keep track of the active crawls.  You have to add `self._crawl(...)` but I don't recommend to do this because you'd be calling a function that the Scrapy authors intended to be private.

Just as a learning excercise, this is what your code would looked like if you don't change your `TwistedRunner`

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def scrape(self, request):
   ds= set()
   Runner = TwistedRunner()
   ds.add(Runner.crawl(MySpider1))
   ds.add(Runner.crawl(MySpider2))
   ds.add(Runner.crawl(MySpider3))
   return defer.gatherResults(ds)
```

Since your `Runner.crawl()` returns a deferred, this example adds them to a set, which you then wait for using [defer.gatherResults()](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.html#gatherResults).

Finally, this is what you should do.  Don't subclass your own `CrawlerRunner` and just use the class as is.  Follow the example on the Scrapy docs and you will be able to scrape using multiple spiders.

Comment: Thank you! I update my `def scrape()`according to your suggestions, plus adding the original callback:
`ds.addCallback(getSpiderResult)
return ds`

Comment: it seems like there is new trouble ahead. However everything is working, the crawler-results are saved N-times via item-pipeline, where N is the number of spiders running. I can extract only the first full result-frame, but why does this happen? Thanks